# What bodies are bound by the public interest test when prosecuting a crime?

Tags: england-and-wales, prosecution

ThE CPS clearly is held to this test, but what about other entities bringing prosecutions? Like local authorities, other public bodies, or even privately owned companies? Where is the line drawn?